# binding text on radiobutton selection

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a WPF form that contains 2 radiobutton and one label. I need to change label text depending on radiobutton selection

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="True">
        <TextBlock Text="First"/> 
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton>
        <TextBlock Text="Second"/>
</RadioButton>
```

And label as the text block

```
<TextBlock  Text=""/>
```

What is the better way to bind TextBlock Text property on radiobutton selection?

Answer (score 0):

well the best would be to bind isChecked to a property and text to another property

```
<RadioButton Content = "First" IsChecked="{Binding Value1}"/>
<RadioButton Content = "Second" IsChecked="{Binding Value2}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
```

then when property is set change text

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Enum property that would hold a value indicating which RadioButton is currently checked. Then the same field would be used in a converter to return the text you want.